# Puppet root authorized_key file

Tags: ssh, puppet, authorized-keys

I've been messing around with puppet and i ran into an issue that has stumped me.
maybe some one can shed some light. The idea is I have an rsync script that updates my authorized_keys
file on my puppet master. Every 4 hours puppet agent grabs the new authorized_keys file.

here is a Master manifest

```
class policy1::sshkey {
  file { '/root/.ssh/':
    ensure  =>  directory,
    path    =>  '/root/.ssh/',
    owner   =>  'root',
    group   =>  'root',
    mode    =>   '0700',
  }

  file { '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys':
    require => File ["/root/.ssh/authorized_keys"],
    ensure  => file,
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    mode    => '0600',
    source  => "puppet:///modules/policy1/authorized_keys",
  }
}
```

my agent though gets this error

> Error: Failed to apply catalog: Not a directory - /root/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: Can you make sure that on the master, `modules/policy1/files/authorized_keys` is not a directory?

Comment: Yes, it is not a directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your manifest, specifically the second resource definition you have it requiring itself. That said, you wanna do something like below:

```
class policy1::sshkey {
  file { '/root/.ssh/':
    ensure =>  directory,
    path   =>  '/root/.ssh/',
    owner  =>  'root',
    group  =>  'root',
    mode   =>   '0700',
  }

  file { '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys':
    # Require the parent directory to be created beforehand.
    require => File['/root/.ssh/'],
    ensure  => file,
    owner   => 'root',
    group   => 'root',
    mode    => '0600',
    source  => "puppet:///modules/policy1/authorized_keys",
  }
}
```

... or I personally prefer:

```
class policy1::sshkey {
  file { '/root/.ssh':
    ensure => directory,
    path   => '/root/.ssh',
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    mode   => '0700',
  }->
  file { '/root/.ssh/authorized_keys':
    ensure => file,
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    mode   => '0600',
    source => 'puppet:///modules/policy1/authorized_keys',
  }
}
```

Comment: So I disabled the bottom half of the manifest and I can confirm the top half works
     class policy1::sshkeys {
      file { '/root/.ssh':
        ensure => directory,
        path   => '/root/.ssh',
        owner  => 'root',
        group  => 'root',
        mode   => '0700',

Comment: So i disabled the top half and can validate it works. So i think the issue might be the second part, if I disabled ensure => file it works. I am able to see the pre-seeded authorized_keys from the master.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like disabling the
    ensure => file,
seems to do the trick. Thanks Evgeny and Felix for your help.